# SQL order individual columns separately

Tags: sql

I want to order columns of data separately - i.e. have both columns ordered by value independently of one another (removing the links between data in each columns). How can I do this without using multiple 'select' clauses?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: You will lose relations between them?

Comment: You can't really do it without using separate SELECTs as far as I know. The normal behaviour of SELECT is to return columns of related data (i.e. data from the same row, or from a related row in another table). In fact that's kind of the whole point of a relational database. But...why do you want to do this anyway? Surely your output will be meaningless if you just have lots of lists where it's unclear which data items belong together? What exactly is the use case / requirement for what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be done any simpler than this (SQL Server):

```
;with cte as (
  select 
    COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE ,
    rwn1 = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by column_name),
    rwn2 = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by data_type)
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
)
select 
  c1.COLUMN_NAME, c2.DATA_TYPE
from cte c1
join cte c2
  on c1.rwn1=c2.rwn2
order by 
  c1.rwn1
```

Comment: That's invalid standard SQL, please mention the DBMS for which this works (the question is only tagged with `sql` not a specific database product)